# What jobs exempted one from being conscripted in the UK during World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two, united-kingdom, conscription

During the Second World War, what jobs in the United Kingdom meant that their holders were exempt from being called up for military service?

Comment: What research have you done? For example, googling your question directed me to [parliament.uk](https://www.parliament.uk/about/living-heritage/transformingsociety/private-lives/yourcountry/overview/conscriptionww2/), which informs me that "Those medically unfit were exempted, as were others in key industries and jobs such as baking, farming, medicine, and engineering.   "  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Have we had this question before? Or a US variant of it?

Comment: Early in WWII, the army did a blunder - a fair number in the 60000 force of constables/police in England was reservists and then duly called up.  The crime rate went up a bit and also the work-load for the remaining police men.

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, jobs that were exempted in the UK were coal mining, ship building and engineering related activities. However,they could still join the Home Guard.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_occupation

Answer (score 2):

Great question. According to the British parliaments website, the majority of those who got exempted were either medically unfit or worked in key industries. The link to the website is below.

https://www.parliament.uk/about/living-heritage/transformingsociety/private-lives/yourcountry/overview/conscriptionww2/

Comment: Hi Dantheanimator and welcome to History SE. Your answer would be improved by saying what those key industries were. Note that sometimes links rot, in which case the information will be lost unless it's in your answer.

Comment: Thank you Lars for the advice. I'll try not to make the same mistake again.